# unable to stream the hls content from gstreamer pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04

Could you please help me to fix this issue?
I am new to gstreamer and pipeline facing tough time to debug below issue

I am trying to do hls stteam of video capture output using gst-launch-1.0 command
I run below command in ubuntu 18.04

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,framerate=30000/1001,width=720,height=480 ! x264enc bitrate=256 
! muxer.sink_65 audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=1 
! avenc_aac bitrate=32000 ! muxer.sink_66 mpegtsmux name=muxer prog-map=program_map,
sink_65=10,sink_66=10 ! tee name=output_tee ! queue ! 
hlssink location=/var/www/segment-%05d.ts playlist-location=/var/www/index.m3u8 max-files=20 target-duration=15

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I am using HD60 Game Live video capture card which support [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed) video codec

```
Linux 8d78e22141e4 4.15.0-91-generic #92~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 14:57:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@8d78e22141e4:/code# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```